# MYSQL Join two tables and combine row values

Tags: mysql, join, concatenation

I have a MySQL database with two tables:

Table 1:

```
    Product_ID | Product_Name | Product_Description
    ------------------------------------------------
    1          | Coca-Cola    | Coke description.
    2          | Pepsi        | Pepsi description.
    3          | Fanta        | Fanta description
    ...
```

Table 2:

```
    Product_ID | Product_SKU | Product_Size | Product_Price
    ------------------------------------------------
    1          | COKE330     | 330ml        | 0.79
    1          | COKE500     | 500ml        | 1.29
    2          | PEPS330     | 330ml        | 0.59
    2          | PEPS500     | 500ml        | 0.99
    ...
```

I want to query the database and join these two tables together but merge duplicate rows with the same product id so the returned result ends up looking like:

```
    Product_ID | Product_Name | Product_Sizes | Product_Prices | Product_Description
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1          | Coca-Cola    | 330ml, 500ml  | 0.79, 1.29     | Coke description.
    2          | Pepsi        | 330ml, 500ml  | 0.59, 0.99     | Pepsi description.
    ...
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?

Comment: Can you please post the insert and create scripts, so it will be easy to analyse and answer correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group the rows and use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to assemble the grouped values, as in:

```
select
  a.product_id,
  max(a.product_name),
  group_concat(b.product_size) as product_sizes,
  group_concat(b.product_price) as product_prices,
  a.product_description
from table1 a
join table2 b on b.product_id = a.product_id
group by a.product_id
```